# Is it possible to add suffix as regex in $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader in AngularJS Translation?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

In AngularJS translation config can we have $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader suffix property as an regex.

Lets say below is a sample config :

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            files: [{
                prefix: 'i18n/local-',
                suffix: '.json'
            }]
        });
        $translateProvider
            .preferredLanguage("en");
```

Instead suffix to be '.json', is it possible to make it as

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
            $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
                files: [{
                    prefix: 'i18n/local-',
                   suffix: '-[0-9a-f]{8,10}-?.json'
                }]
            });
            $translateProvider
                .preferredLanguage("en");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not and it is easy to understand why, $translate need to be able to build the exact url of your file. So if you start with :

```
  prefix: 'i18n/local-',
  suffix: '.json'
```

The url for en will be `il8n/local-en.json`.

If you use a regex as a suffix, how can he build the full URL of the file ? It just can't.

EDIT :

The OP goal was to trick the cache : here is the solution given :

prefix: 'i18n/local-',
   suffix: '.json?random='+generateRandomString()

Comment: Thanks for the response, You have any idea how to randomize it.

Comment: To be honest i don't get your point, but what you could do is to generate a random suffix : `suffix:randomString()+'.json` and server-side have a piece of code intercepting call to i18n and serving the file. However as long the user don't refresh the page, the suffix will be the same for that user, but it will be different on each tab he opens

Comment: we have added a gulp rev to randomize the json , now the problem to update the same in app.translate.config.js

Comment: sure but what is the purpose of randomizing the json filename ? To trick the cache ? If so something like : suffix :'.json?random=new Date().getSeconds()'  would be faire enough. While keeping the filename preserved

Comment: yes, that what it is meant.. oh... did not thought of an this much easy solution.. how confident you are that this will work .. :)

Comment: @Dreamweaver if you search for 'trick IE javascript file cache' this is the typical solution given :)